# How do I reuse a socket after it forcibly closes?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

So I am currently learning about [Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8) and I've managed to create a Server which accepts connections and a Client which connects to a Server.

When the `Client` connects to the `Server` the Server the reacts by showing a `MessageBox` saying `"Client Connected"`. Super simple and it works like a charm.

However, if I then close the client it would normally throw a `SocketException` explaining that, "Hey, the client was forcibly closed" which is understandable, it's kinda hard to receive any data when the connection is broken.

So what I did was that I Implemented the `Socket.Poll` function to determine the status of the socket and with that being done it stopped throwing the exception because I am now handling it.
I never said I did it in a good way, It's just being dealt with and this is where I seek help.

Now if the `Client` crashes or forcibly closes, it doesn't throw an error but when I try to connect again the `Server` doesn't react and it doesn't invoke the `Callback` function.

The `Client` connects to the `Server` but the `Server` doesn't show the `MessageBox` that a `Client` has conencted.
Why is that?

This is how I start it
Server

```
private void StartUp()
        {
            ServerSocket.Bind(7777);
            ServerSocket.Listen(500);
            ServerSocket.AcceptConnectionAsync();
...
```

And here is the ServerSocket object

```
class ServerSocket
    {
        private static readonly Socket _SERVER_SOCKET = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static byte[] RECEIVED_BUFFER;

        public ServerSocket()
        {

        }

        public static void Bind(int port)
        {
            _SERVER_SOCKET.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        }

        public static void Listen(int backLog)
        {
            _SERVER_SOCKET.Listen(backLog);
        }


        public static void AcceptConnectionAsync()
        {
            _SERVER_SOCKET.BeginAccept(ConnectionAcceptedCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ConnectionAcceptedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            //Once this function gets invoked we can stop that specific one
            //and store the socket instance in a variable.
            var ACCEPTED_SOCKET = _SERVER_SOCKET.EndAccept(ar);

            MessageBox.Show("Client connected.");

            //Clear the BUFFER before passing it into the callback
            RECEIVED_BUFFER = new byte[1024];
            //Starts receiving data and store it in the BUFFER
            //Once data has been received, invoke the callback.
            ACCEPTED_SOCKET.BeginReceive(RECEIVED_BUFFER, 0, RECEIVED_BUFFER.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                ReceivedDataCallback, ACCEPTED_SOCKET);

        }

        private static void ReceivedDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            //Null cast the AsyncResult parameter as a Socket.
            var CLIENT_SOCKET = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
            if (!CLIENT_SOCKET.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                //Used to theow an exception if the client forcibly closed.
                //but it stopped since I'm using "Poll" now.
                var BUFFER_SIZE = CLIENT_SOCKET.EndReceive(ar);

                var PACKET = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                Array.Copy(RECEIVED_BUFFER, PACKET, PACKET.Length);

                //Handle the packet.

                MessageBox.Show($"{CLIENT_SOCKET.RemoteEndPoint}: {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PACKET)}");
            }
            else
            {
                CLIENT_SOCKET.Disconnect(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I start the Client

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7777));


            while (true)
                Console.Read();
        }
```

And the ClientSocket object

```
class ClientSocket
    {
        private static readonly Socket CLIENT_SOCKET =  new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public ClientSocket()
        {

        }


        public static void Connect(IPEndPoint Endpoint)
        {
            CLIENT_SOCKET.Connect(Endpoint);

            if (CLIENT_SOCKET.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server.");

                CLIENT_SOCKET.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World!"), SocketFlags.None);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my experience, a disconnected client will trigger a "data ready" event and return 0 bytes read when you try to read from it. That 0 bytes read is the indicator that the other end has closed the connection. I've never used async with sockets though and just always relied on [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.select?view=netframework-4.8) to detect new connections and to find out when a socket is ready for reading or writing, so YMMV. `Poll()` should work similarly, but I'm not sure with the async calls.

Comment: I guess I could rely on the 0 bytes that it returns and then try to close the connection on the server end. The issue here is that the server doesn't recognize it as a connection again when I try to connect if that makes any sense.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, you'll need to instantiate a new socket. Once a socket has been closed, it can't be reused.

Comment: I simply forgot to start accepting connections again.. It went over my head and I thought it would just start automatically since async but nope. If you want to use that as an asnwer I'll accept it. :-)